# Portable RAM disk for Windows (gratis)

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management, portable, in-memory-database

I am searching for a RAM disk program for Windows.

The requirements are quite minimal, but after much searching, I feel like I am looking for a unicorn.

Here are the only requirements:

1. Portable
2. Gratis

That's it!

Open-source is a plus, but not required.  Compatibility with any recent version of Windows (7-10) is fine.

It does not need any special features, such as restoring itself after reboot.  It doesn't even need to allow the user to set the capacity, as long as the RAM drive is at least 200MB.

Comment: Portable will limit the result to probably 0.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks Thomas. I'm concerned about that too. In the distant corners of my mind, I seem to recall a Windows RAM disk that was either just a simple executable or an executable with one additional file. But after much searching, I haven't been able to find a reference to it.  If such a unicorn does not actually exist, I think I can work with something that I can *manually* install and uninstall.  In other words, something where I can perform the required system changes by hand, and also undo them manually.